# PHP exec troubleshooting

Tags: php, linux, bash, exec

First, my OS is Fedora 20.

Here is a snippet from ll

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache       91 Dec 31 01:47 block.php
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root         67 Dec 31 01:27 clear
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root         10 Nov 27 14:48 eula.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root         53 Dec 23 00:38 index.php
-rwxr-xr-x 1 apache apache       95 Dec 31 01:12 ipblock
```

`is_writable` returns `1` (true);
whoami returns apache when running `exec('whoami');` in a php file.

As you can see that is set.

I saw a little about PATH variables but not sure where that was leading.

Here is the exact code of block.php

```
 cat block.php
<?php
   $is=is_writable(ipblock);
   echo $is;
   $output = system("sh ipblock");
   echo $output;
?>
```

should simply add the IP 44.44.44.44 to iptables. Simple enough. Contents of ipblock

```
cat ipblock
iptables -A INPUT -s 44.44.44.44 -j DROP
service iptables save
service iptables restart
```

Two simple files with less than 10 lines of code total.

I have ensured that the file is writable, owns to the correct user, and still. no luck.

So to summarize

Problem: block.php works from command line and fully executes, however, web based it does not.

What should happen: Ip 44.44.44.44 gets blocked by iptables.

Other info: When run from root whoami does return root, but when run from web, user returns apache. I have a feeling somewhere there is the key but I am totally missing this.

Comment: `$is=is_writable(ipblock);` doesn't sound right. It should be: `$is=is_writable('ipblock');`, right?

Comment: 'tail /var/log/apache2/error.log' please

Comment: Try using `exec` instead of `system`

Comment: I've used shell_exec, exec, and currently with system. Give me a moment to tail that log.

Comment: iptables v1.4.19.1: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Permission denied (you must be root)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
/usr/libexec/iptables/iptables.init: line 53: /etc/sysconfig/iptables-config: Permission denied
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl restart  iptables.service
Failed to issue method call: Access denied


Perhaps I may not be able to do iptables from a PHP script.